# Why can't I access this global variable?

Tags: php

I of course tried it with out the `$GLOBALS` and still no go.  Is my syntax correct.  My understanding is that `$DB_USER` is in the global scope.

```
<?php
    $DB_USER = 'foo';
    class Database
    {
        // this does not work
        private $DB_USER =              $GLOBALS['DB_USER'];
        private $DB_PASS =              'foob';
        private $DB_DRIVER =            'foob_foob';
        // ...
```

Comment: try `private $DB_USER = $DB_USER`, but `$GLOBALS` is evil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `$DB_USER` from inside of your class method, which means you are actually calling the variable from the local scope (within the class). To fix this, just tell PHP that you're looking for the global variable by adding `global $DB_USER` inside of your methods where it will be used (or use your constructor to add it to the class scope):

```
class Database
{  
    private $DB_USER =              '';
    private $DB_PASS =              'foob';
    private $DB_DRIVER =            'foob_foob';
    // snip


   // Method 1: Add the variable to the class scope with the constructor        
   public function __construct() 
   {
      global $DB_USER;
      $this->DB_USER = $DB_USER;
   }


   // Method 2: tell PHP that you want the global variable in your methods
   public function foo() 
   {
      $global $DB_USER;
      ...
    }
```

With method 1, you can now call `$this->DB_USER` instead of  `$GLOBALS['DB_USER']`.

With method 2, you add `global $DB_USER` to each, and then just use `$DB_USER`.

For more information see http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 0):

Use constructor to initialize your varibale:

```
public function __constructor(){
    global $YOUR_VARIABLE;
    $DB_USER = $YOUR_VARIABLE;
}
```

Comment: you declare outside, but use constructor to initialize default varbiale.

Answer (score 0):

So, you declare your `variables` first and initialize them in the `__construct` method

```
$DB_USER = 'foo';
class Database
{
    private $DB_USER,
    $DB_PASS,
    $DB_DRIVER;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->DB_USER = $GLOBALS['DB_USER'];
        $this->DB_PASS = 'foob';
        $this->DB_DRIVER = 'foob_foob';
        print_r($this);
    }
}

new Database();
```

This will output

```
Database Object
(
    [DB_USER:Database:private] => foo
    [DB_PASS:Database:private] => foob
    [DB_DRIVER:Database:private] => foob_foob
)
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/bd0S79)**

**EDIT**

Using Dependency Injection:

```
$DB_USER = 'foo';
class Database
{
    private $DB_USER,
    $DB_PASS,
    $DB_DRIVER;
    public function __construct($dbUser){
        $this->DB_USER = $dbUser;
        $this->DB_PASS = 'foob';
        $this->DB_DRIVER = 'foob_foob';
        print_r($this);
    }
}

new Database($DB_USER);
```

**[DEMO_2](http://ideone.com/YDek7b)**

Comment: If you're using a constructor, then far, far better to DI the $DB_USER value

Comment: OP wants these variables set at the very top, so I guess using constructor is better.

Comment: That doesn't negate passing the value as an argument to the constructor, which is far better than using $GLOBALS

Comment: @MarkBaker, while I agree with you 100% about DI, OP's issue is due to a lack of understanding of variable scopes. That being the case, wouldn't it be better to correct his original problem (and shine light on the subject of variable scopes) than trying to introduce him to DI? I'd like to get your opinion on the matter.

Comment: This is actually down to "run-time" evaluation of `$GLOBALS['DB_USER'];` rather than a variable-scope issue; Access to $GLOBALS is run-time - `[property] declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated`

Comment: I see your demo, but this clearly does not work for me... maybe it is a version issue, I have to explicitly declare using the global keyword or it will not work ... also it does not require a string, but just the variable `GLOBALS[VARIABLE]` ... very weird .

Comment: @MarkBaker: Thank you for taking the time to explain the technicals behind this problem. $GLOBALS being evaluated JIT is definitely an important distinction that should be noted.